# Slick Slider Center Mode doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I use the Center Mode from the Slick Slider. Now i have the problem that i want the slider in full width and that the centered Image is much larger than the slides. I added a image from the template:

[Slider Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lwMK.png)

My site ist hosted on: http://be-virtual.org/schnittchen/

My Code is the following
Javascript:

```js
     $(document).on('ready', function() {

      
$('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
  

    });
```

```css
.slick-center .slide-h3{
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .slider{
    width: 600px;  
    height:150px;
    margin: 20px auto;    
    text-align: center;
  }

.slider button {
  background: #000;
}

.slider button:hover button:active button:visited {
  background: #000;
}

  .slide-h3{
    margin: 10% 0 10% 0;
    padding: 40% 20%;
    background: #008ed6;
  }
  .slider div{
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .slick-slide{
    opacity: .6;
  }
  .slick-center{
    display: block;
    max-width: 10% !important;
    max-height:20% !important;
    opacity: 1;


  }
```

```html
 <section class="center slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">
    </div>
```

Sorry iam new at the coding and new in this community. Please have some 
patience and indulgence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade your slick min js file use latest version
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.5/slick.min.js

Comment: Thank you for that information. I updated my file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters your jquery setup is wrong. It should begin with `$(document).ready(function(){` and not  `$(document).on('ready', function() {`. In your CSS it looks like you have set a `width` to the slideshow but not to the images themselves, is that correct? In that case, try setting the images to the same fixed `width` as your slideshow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The css and html markup are from the demo site. I just want that the gallery is responsive too.

Comment: Ok, now i updated the css a little bit and the result is better as at the beginning. Now the problem is that all Images have the same size. But in the demo the centered Image is much larger than the other... Know anyone where is the failure?